# Alpine $dispatch event not firing (or not listened to)

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, alpine.js

I wrote a simple component that implements the [Suneditor](http://suneditor.com/sample/index.html). It's supposed to be used in the context of another livewire component.
The problem is that, after typing into I would suppose the input event to be fired and the `$content` variable to be updated. But this is not happening.

**The editor component:**
*editor.php*

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components\inputs;

use Illuminate\View\Component;
use Str;

class editor extends Component
{
    public $componentKey;
    public $initialContent;
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($initialContent)
    {
        $this->componentKey = Str::random();
        $this->initialContent = $initialContent;
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Closure|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.inputs.editor');
    }
}
```

*editor.blade.php*

```
    <div class="z-0" wire:key="{{ Str::random() }}" wire:ignore x-data="{
                            value: '{{$initialContent}}',
                            init() {
                                var parent = this;
                                const editor = SUNEDITOR.create(($refs.{{ 'edit'.$componentKey }}),{
                                        imageUploadHeader: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.head.querySelector('meta[name=csrf-token]').content},
                                        imageUploadUrl: '/bild-speichern',
                                        lang: SUNEDITOR_LANG['en'],
                                        'minHeight': '250px',
                                        width: '100%',
                                        buttonList: [
                                            ['undo', 'redo'],
                                            ['formatBlock'],
                                            ['paragraphStyle', 'blockquote'],
                                            ['bold', 'underline', 'italic', 'strike', 'subscript', 'superscript'],
                                            ['fontColor', 'hiliteColor'],
                                            '/', // Line break
                                            ['outdent', 'indent'],
                                            ['align', 'horizontalRule', 'list'],
                                            ['table', 'link', 'image' /** ,'math' */],
                                            ['video'],
                                            ['fontSize', 'font', 'codeView', 'removeFormat']
                                            ]
                                    });

                                    editor.onChange = contents => {
                                        parent.value = contents;
                                        $dispatch('input', contents); // This doesn't seem to work. 
                                        alert('TEST'); // This one works
                            }
                 }
             }">
        <textarea class="w-full" x-ref="{{ 'edit'.$componentKey }}">{!! $initialContent !!}</textarea>
    </div>
```

**surrounding component (partly)**
*text-block-component.blade.php*

```
<x-inputs.editor wire:model="content" :initial-content="$content" wire:key="{{ Str::random() }}"/>
```

*TextBlockComponent.php (partly)*

```
    public $content = "";
    public function updated()
    {
        echo(""); // Just for the debugger to see if the event gets to the surrounding component
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone stumbles upon this issue too:
The problem was simply a forgotten `{{$attributes}} somewhere inside the div of the blade file`.

```
    <div 
{{$attributes}} // <--- was missing!
class="z-0" wire:key="{{ Str::random() }}" wire:ignore x-data="{
                            value: '{{$initialContent}}',
                            init() {
                                var parent = this;
                                const editor = SUNEDITOR.create(($refs.{{ 'edit'.$componentKey }}),{
                                        imageUploadHeader: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.head.querySelector('meta[name=csrf-token]').content},
                                        imageUploadUrl: '/bild-speichern',
                                        lang: SUNEDITOR_LANG['en'],
                                        'minHeight': '250px',
                                        width: '100%',
                                        buttonList: [
                                            ['undo', 'redo'],
                                            ['formatBlock'],
                                            ['paragraphStyle', 'blockquote'],
                                            ['bold', 'underline', 'italic', 'strike', 'subscript', 'superscript'],
                                            ['fontColor', 'hiliteColor'],
                                            '/', // Line break
                                            ['outdent', 'indent'],
                                            ['align', 'horizontalRule', 'list'],
                                            ['table', 'link', 'image' /** ,'math' */],
                                            ['video'],
                                            ['fontSize', 'font', 'codeView', 'removeFormat']
                                            ]
                                    });

                                    editor.onChange = contents => {
                                        parent.value = contents;
                                        $dispatch('input', contents); // This doesn't seem to work. 
                                        alert('TEST'); // This one works
                            }
                 }
             }">
        <textarea class="w-full" x-ref="{{ 'edit'.$componentKey }}">{!! $initialContent !!}</textarea>
    </div>
```

Comment: I spent good 4-5 hours on it. And you saved me countless more

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an Alpine.js component, so you have to use the [`this` context](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-data#using-magic-properties) (or its `parent` alias you created) to access the magic properties, like `$dispatch`:

```
this.$dispatch('input', contents)
```

Comment: Trying this, I get `this.$dispatch is not a function`. Actually I don't see, why I need `this` here. I just followed the example https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js#forwarding-wire-model-input-events `this` is not used there. I don't get any error not using this, it just (seemingly) does nothing.